# How to view contents of a folder in Centos7 having 7 million+ tiff files?

Tags: directory, centos7, tiff

I am creating sub-images of CT scan data. For every CT image (including all the slices) I get more than 5 million sub-images as tiff files which amounts to more than 10 GB, and are stored in a folder. When I open the folder to view the contents I get a dialogue box saying "Files" is not responding and options of force quit or wait are displayed.

When tens or hundreds of sub-images are stored then the contents of the folder can be viewed and tiff files can be opened using system viewer but with huge data problem occurs.

Expected outcome is I should be able to open the folder containing 7 million tiff files and then open the files using system viewer to view those grey scale sub-images. But, I am unable to open the folder as it hangs or opens a dialogue box of "Files" not responding. What should be the best way to open and view the contents in this case.

Comment: Have you tried console file explorer Midnight Commander (mc)? It should be able to handle it.
Install it if not installed:
`yum install mc -y`
Open the folder containg the TIFF files:
`mc /path/to/the/directory/containing/the/TIFFs`

Comment: @357up My data is getting stored in ext4 filesystem and mc is not accepting it.

Comment: Ultimately MC came to my rescue after numerous system formatting. Thanks